Relay: Expected to receive an object where `...UserForm_user` was spread, but the fragment reference was not found`
I am testing a component with React testing library and Jest.
The component:
import { useMutation, useFragment } from 'react-relay';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useState } from 'react';

const fragment = graphql`
  fragment UserForm_user on User {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    role
  }
`;

const mutation = graphql`
  mutation UserFormMutation($input: UpdateUserInput!) {
    updateUser(input: $input) {
      user {
        id
        databaseId
        role
        firstName
        lastName
      }
      errors {
        field
        messages
      }
    }
  }
`;

Component.displayName = 'UserForm';
export default function Component(props) {
  const data = useFragment(fragment, props.user);

  const [commit, isInFlight] = useMutation(mutation);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

  const [user, setUser] = useState(data);

  const onChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setUser((user) => ({ ...user, [name]: value }));
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    commit({
      variables: {
        input: {
          id: user.id,
          ...user,
        },
      },
      onCompleted: ({ updateUser: { errors } }) => {
        if (errors.length > 0) {
          setErrors(errors);
        }
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Table.Col>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Input
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            errors={errors}
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            value={user.firstName}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Table.Col>
      <Table.Col>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Input
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            errors={errors}
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            value={user.lastName}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Table.Col>
      <Table.Col></Table.Col>
      <Table.Col></Table.Col>
      <Table.Col>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Select id="role" name="role" errors={errors} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} value={user.role}>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="consultant">Consultant</option>
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>
      </Table.Col>
    </>
  );
}

Component.propTypes = {
 


The test :
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest';
import { act, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { RelayEnvironmentProvider } from 'react-relay/hooks';
import { MockPayloadGenerator, createMockEnvironment } from 'relay-test-utils';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

import Component from '../../src/components/UserForm';

describe('UserForm', () => {
  it('submit the form fields', async () => {
    const environment = createMockEnvironment();
    environment.mock.queueOperationResolver((operation) => {
      return MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation, {
        User() {
          return {
            id: 'user-1',
            firstName: 'Chris',
            lastName: 'Koo',
            role: 'admin',
          };
        },
      });
    });

    const user = {
      id: 'user-1',
      firstName: 'Chris',
      lastName: 'Koo',
      role: 'admin',
    };

    render(
      <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={environment}>
        <Component user={user} />
      </RelayEnvironmentProvider>,
    );

    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText('Voornaam'), 'Chris');
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText('Achternaam'), 'Koo');
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText('Gebruiker type'), 'admin');
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Opslaan' }));

    const mutationOperation = environment.mock.getMostRecentOperation();
    expect(mutationOperation.request.variables.input).toEqual({
      id: 'user-1',
      firstName: 'Chris',
      lastName: 'Koo',
      role: 'admin',
    });

    act(() => {
      environment.mock.resolveMostRecentOperation((operation) =>
        MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation, {
          UpdateUser() {
            return {
              user: {
                id: 'user-1',
                databaseId: 1,
                firstName: 'Chris',
                lastName: 'Koo',
                role: 'admin',
              },
              errors: [],
            };
          },
        }),
      );
    });
  });
});

I am getting this error :
Invariant Violation: Relay: Expected to receive an object where ...UserForm_user was spread, but the fragment reference was not found`. This is most likely the result of:

Forgetting to spread UserForm_user in useFragment()'s parent's fragment.
Conditionally fetching UserForm_user but unconditionally passing a fragment reference prop to useFragment(). If the parent fragment only fetches the fragment conditionally - with e.g. @include, @skip, or inside a ... on SomeType { } spread  - then the fragment reference will not exist. In this case, pass null if the conditions for evaluating the fragment are not met (e.g. if the @include(if) value is false.)

can you help with it?

The error happens because useFragment isn’t getting the expected fragment reference. Check if the parent component correctly spreads UserForm_user in its query and make sure it’s not conditionally fetching the data without handling the case where the fragment isn’t available. Also, ensure your test’s mock environment provides the necessary fragment data.
